# How to set hint color for TextInputLayout after lost focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

I am using this below xml code:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtAddress1Current"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_button"
                    android:hint="My Hint" 
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                                                     />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Scenario:
Step 1: Edittext1 is blank- Hinttextcolor = Black.
Step 2: Edittext1 value entered Hinttext = Orange.
 Step 3: Lostfocus from Edittext1 to Edittext2, Edittext1 hinttext=Orange. Used AppcompactEdittext and TextInputLayout.

Please help me out.

Comment: post your style `@style/TextLabel`

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
android:textColorHint="@color/your_color"
```

inside `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Apply `setOnFocusChangeListener(this)`  to the AppCompatEditText
then onfocuschange:

```
@Override 
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.edtAddress1Current && !hasfocus){
         v.setHintTextColor("#FCFCFC")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this..

add in the Parent layout Child..

```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Take where you are using

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout       
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput"
 />
```

set this style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="TextLabelInput" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/solid_red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_red</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using XML:

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
```

Using Java:

```
editText.setHintTextColor( Color.rgb(255,255,255));
```

Comment: *TextInputLayout!!* NOT EditText